# Attempting to restore iPhone 4 gives error -1

Tags: itunes, iphone

I just bought a iPhone 4 off Craigslist, and it's stuck on the iTunes screen. Whenever I try to restore it, towards the end of the process, an icon pops up and says error -1. What does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, [according to Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3694#error-1), `error -1` indicates a hardware issue. Specifically:

> This may indicate a hardware issue with your device. Follow Troubleshooting security software issues, and restore your device on a different known-good computer. If the errors persist on another computer, the device may need service.